# what is the best method to read data from a text/data file

Tags: java, object, io

```
 package mp1similar;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.StringTokenizer;
 import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MP1Similar 
{

private static ArrayList arrayList  ;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
 ArrayList arrayList= null;
    try 
    {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/Catalog.txt"));

    String line="";
    arrayList =new ArrayList();
    while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
        {
      //  System.out.println(line);
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
            //System.out.println(st.nextToken());
            arrayList.add(st.nextToken());
            System.out.println(br.readLine());
            }
        }
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
         System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }
catch (IOException ex)
    {
          System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
          ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

I am trying to pass data from a TXT file to an array of objects. The TXT fil elooks something like this:

4950331 hist 
    37.5    121.5   --- AS  -   5.2 1.0

8270000 hist 
    51.10   12.80   --- EU  -   4.8 1.0

The data is separated by whitespace's. All the contents have to be transferred to objects.

Comment: What's the question, what doesn't work?

Comment: This is the code that I was given. Im a newbie to java , so my question would be :- are we transferring all the data to Arraylist? How can I retrieve all the data ( display it onthe screen or print it to another file ) in an organised fashion . The first column is date , second is something else and so forth.

Comment: The line `System.out.println(br.readLine());` causing reader to fetch next line and just print it out. In other words, line is not parsed. Is that expected behavior?

Comment: You can ignore that line , I just wanted to see what the output would be.

Comment: what do you mean by parsing if I may ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will print everything in the ArrayList to the screen:

```
    for(int i=0;i< arrayList.size();i++){
        System.out.println(arrayList.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend to use [FileUtils.readFileToString()](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) from Apache `commons-io` package. Don't reinvent the wheel, just use the library.

Comment: thank you , let me research that

Comment: [FileUtils.readLines()](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines(java.io.File)) might be more appropriate in this case.

Comment: when i try to import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; i get an error saying package does not exist

Comment: Download their JAR and add it to classpath first: http://commons.apache.org/io/download_io.cgi